# How to preg_match() a variable from file_get_contents()

Tags: php, preg-match, file-get-contents, google-trends

I've created a very basic script which gets the data from a url with PHP (For Google trends):

```
$url = 'https://www.google.com/trends/fetchComponent?hl=en-US&q=battlefield%201&cid=TIMESERIES_GRAPH_0&export=5&w=500&h=300&gprop=youtube&date=today%201-m';
$url2 = file_get_contents($url);
```

In the source code there's a certain type of data I want to extract

```
{"columns":[{"id":"d","label":"Date","type":"datetime"},{"role":"annotation","type":"string"},{"p":{"html":true},"role":"annotationText","type":"string"},{"id":"q0","label":"battlefield 1","type":"number"},{"role":"annotation","type":"string"},{"p":{"html":true},"role":"annotationText","type":"string"},{"role":"certainty","type":"boolean"}],"headlineDataPoints":[],"width":485,"axisAnnotations":[],"rows":[[{"v":new Date(2016, 8, 24, 12, 0),"f":"Saturday, September 24, 2016"},null,null,21,null,null,true],[{"v":new Date(2016, 8, 25, 12, 0),"f":"Sunday, September 25, 2016"},null,null,23,null,null,true],[{"v":new Date(2016, 8, 26, 12, 0),"f":"Monday, September 26, 2016"},null,null,19,null,null,true],[{"v":new Date(2016, 8, 27, 12, 0),"f":"Tuesday, September 27, 2016"},null,null,44,null,null,true],[{"v":new Date(2016, 8, 28, 12, 0),"f":"Wednesday, September 28, 2016"},null,null,54,null,null,true],[{"v":new Date(2016, 8, 29, 12, 0),"f":"Thursday, September 29, 2016"},null,null,39,null,null,true],[{"v":new Date(2016, 8, 30, 12, 0),"f":"Friday, September 30, 2016"},null,null,35,null,null,true],[{"v":new Date(2016, 9, 1, 12, 0),"f":"Saturday, October 1, 2016"},null,null,38,null,null,true],[{"v":new Date(2016, 9, 2, 12, 0),"f":"Sunday, October 2, 2016"},null,null,64,null,null,true],[{"v":new Date(2016, 9, 3, 12, 0),"f":"Monday, October 3, 2016"},null,null,46,null,null,true],[{"v":new Date(2016, 9, 4, 12, 0),"f":"Tuesday, October 4, 2016"},null,null,35,null,null,true],[{"v":new Date(2016, 9, 5, 12, 0),"f":"Wednesday, October 5, 2016"},null,null,34,null,null,true],[{"v":new Date(2016, 9, 6, 12, 0),"f":"Thursday, October 6, 2016"},null,null,34,null,null,true],[{"v":new Date(2016, 9, 7, 12, 0),"f":"Friday, October 7, 2016"},null,null,31,null,null,true],[{"v":new Date(2016, 9, 8, 12, 0),"f":"Saturday, October 8, 2016"},null,null,29,null,null,true],[{"v":new Date(2016, 9, 9, 12, 0),"f":"Sunday, October 9, 2016"},null,null,30,null,null,true],[{"v":new Date(2016, 9, 10, 12, 0),"f":"Monday, October 10, 2016"},null,null,31,null,null,true],[{"v":new Date(2016, 9, 11, 12, 0),"f":"Tuesday, October 11, 2016"},null,null,22,null,null,true],[{"v":new Date(2016, 9, 12, 12, 0),"f":"Wednesday, October 12, 2016"},null,null,40,null,null,true],[{"v":new Date(2016, 9, 13, 12, 0),"f":"Thursday, October 13, 2016"},null,null,63,null,null,true],[{"v":new Date(2016, 9, 14, 12, 0),"f":"Friday, October 14, 2016"},null,null,55,null,null,true],[{"v":new Date(2016, 9, 15, 12, 0),"f":"Saturday, October 15, 2016"},null,null,71,null,null,true],[{"v":new Date(2016, 9, 16, 12, 0),"f":"Sunday, October 16, 2016"},null,null,64,null,null,true],[{"v":new Date(2016, 9, 17, 12, 0),"f":"Monday, October 17, 2016"},null,null,84,null,null,true],[{"v":new Date(2016, 9, 18, 12, 0),"f":"Tuesday, October 18, 2016"},null,null,100,null,null,true],[{"v":new Date(2016, 9, 19, 12, 0),"f":"Wednesday, October 19, 2016"},null,null,null,null,null,true],[{"v":new Date(2016, 9, 20, 12, 0),"f":"Thursday, October 20, 2016"},null,null,null,null,null,true],[{"v":new Date(2016, 9, 21, 12, 0),"f":"Friday, October 21, 2016"},null,null,null,null,null,true],[{"v":new Date(2016, 9, 22, 12, 0),"f":"Saturday, October 22, 2016"},null,null,null,null,null,true],[{"v":new Date(2016, 9, 23, 12, 0),"f":"Sunday, October 23, 2016"},null,null,null,null,null,true]],"showHeadlines":false,"percentData":false,"colors":["#3f85f2"],"height":230}
```

How can I use preg_match to find this? I've tried

```
$data = preg_match('/^(var chartData = |; var htmlChart)\\/$/', $url2, $output_array);
print_r($output_array);
```

I used the first and last keywords to try and get what's inbetween them (Being the data i want)

I've tried using phpliveregex which actually does sort of pick up what I want (finding the var chartData string) http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/hCB yet when i try to clone that it doesnt work.

My question being, how can I extract this json object (inside the chartData variable) from Google trends using preg_match() because what i've tried hasn't been working.

Comment: Why aren't you simply using json_decode and accessing the property directly?

Comment: @useyourillusiontoo Impossible to tell from the extremely vague question title. But he's trying to extract the JSOX from somewhere within some JS/HTML, but his regex is somewhat cobbled together. (It's also not really JSON.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be helpfull

```
preg_match('/chartData\s+=\s+\{(.+)\}/', $url2,    $output_array);
$charData = $output_array[0];
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to come from several values in the "JSON string" that look all like `new Date(2016, 9, 14, 12, 0)` that contains spaces and are not enclosed between quotes. You can solve the problem adding quotes around them:

```
$str = preg_replace('~:(new Date\([^)]*\))~', ':"$1"', $str);
$jsonArray = json_decode($str, true);
```

Comment: My bad, I'm not very good at explaining things, My actual answer referred to getting the JSON data from the string of html, which @Marcus answered. Thankfully however you did answer this because that would have been my next problem!